# Cannot import model from .models file to nested app sub_directory

Tags: python, django

I suspect that I am not understanding something about django. I am trying to test the file scrape.py which calls an api and parses then writes the response to the model `CMC` in the models.py using sqlalchemy. I am trying to test it to see if the file itself will run but (here's where I think I'm going wrong) I am pressing the play button while having the scrape.py file pulled up in vscode. I suspect there is something here that Django won't allow but am not familiar enough with django to know if that is the case. It is throwing a ModuleNotFound error as described below but I suspect that it's doing that because I am calling it because when I type the dot after `apis` after `import` at the top of the file it shows a list of all the drop-down files in my apis app.
Here is my project tree:

```
(base) justinbenfit@MacBook-Pro-3 cds_website % tree
.
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── serializers.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── management
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── commands
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   │   └── private.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   ├── private.py
│   │   │   └── scrape.py
│   │   └── test.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── cds_website
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── requirements.txt
```

api is an app in a greater project called cds_website. The settings.py file in cds_website project directory contains the following installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'environ'
]
```

and my apps.py file in the api app contains the following class:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'api'
```

CMC is a model in my models.py file. I am trying to import it into scrape.py. I have tried:
`from ...models import CMC`
`from api.models import CMC`
`from ... import CMC`

first one throws: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package second one throws: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api' third one throws: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Here is a link to the code repo: https://github.com/Justinbenfit23/cds_website

Everything I have read indicates that at least one of these should work. Any direction appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm teste your project with `from api.models import CMC` and it's worked

Comment: Thank you @momati! Should I be able to make the file run by just typing python manage.py scrape.py? Or how can I get just that scrape.py file to run?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create **ecrape_manage.py** in **cds_website-master**
folder, content of **ecrape_manage.py**:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cds_website.settings")
import django
django.setup()
exec(open("api/management/commands/scrape.py").read())
```

and just run with **python ecrape_manage.py**

Comment: This way is better